# How to find the mean and the variance of the normal distribution obtained using the advi method in PyMC?

Tags: pymc3, pymc

I am using the advi method to find the posterior distribution. How can I find the mean and the std of the normal posterior distribution that we get using the advi and not that of the samples obtained using advi in PyMC?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `approx.mean.eval()`, `approx.std.eval()`, and then reference `approx.ordering` to map index-slices to parameters of Your model.

Using pymc==4.1.6,
and having defined a `pm.Model` called `model`,
I can do the following:

```
with model:
    approx = pm.fit(method="advi")
    
approx_mu = approx.mean.eval()
approx_mu_dict = {
    param: approx_mu[slice_]
    for (param, (_, slice_, _, _))
    in approx.ordering.items()}

approx_std = approx.std.eval()
approx_std_dict = {
    param: approx_std[slice_]
    for (param, (_, slice_, _, _))
    in approx.ordering.items()}
```